# What is difference between "multo" and "multe"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

In [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#multe) *multe* has several meanings, including

> II- Uzata subst-e., kun la signifo «amaso, granda kvanto, granda nombro»

Similarly, *multo* means

> Amaso, granda kvanto aŭ nombro.

Both definitions come with a lot of examples but I can not see any difference between them. Is there any difference between *multo* and *multe*(II)?

Comment: I'm thinking that *multo* is used where *a lot* is used in English, while *multe* is used like *much*. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adverbs of quantity, like *multe*, *kelke* and *sufiĉe*, can function like nouns, i.e. be used as synonyms for *multo*, *kelko* and *sufiĉo*. This is explained well in [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kvantaj_vortoj/e-vortoj.html#i-zsp). Zamenhof already made this synonymity apparent in the *Fundamento de Esperanto*, where one can find the following sentence:

> Sur la arbo sin trovis multe (aŭ multo) da birdoj.

So in this sentence, "multe da birdoj" means the same as "multo da birdoj".

Of course, there are situations where only *multe* can be used, as an adverb is required. Here are some examples:

- Ni multe dancis dum la [IJK](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internacia_Junulara_Kongreso).
- Mi multe amas ŝin. (Here one can also use *tre* instead of *multe*.)
- Ŝi estas multe pli alta ol li.

But whenever you can use *multo*, you can also use *multe*, and actually *multe* is more common than *multo* in situations where either one is correct. Here are some examples:

- Li havas multe/multon da mono.
- Mi havas multe/multon por rakonti.
- Multe/Multo okazis dum la pasintaj semajnoj.

Somewhat special is the situation with *pluvi*, which usually does not take a subject, but may take one, if one wants to indicate that something other than rainwater fell in a rain-like way (see [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/sensubjektaj.html#i-o5s)). To say that it rained a lot, one would normally say *Pluvis multe*. Here *pluvis* does not have any subject, and *multe* functions in an adverbial way, not like a noun. But since *pluvis* can also take a subject, the sentence *Pluvis multo* is also grammatically correct. However, as *pluvi* is normally only used with a subject when something other than rainwater falls in a rain-like way, *Pluvis multo* would probably be understood to mean 'A lot of things rained', rather than 'It rained a lot'.

Answer (score 6):

It just depends on what allows for you to best articulate yourself. *Multo* is a noun, *multe* is an adverb.

Here's an instance where *multo* must be used because it can stand alone as a subject:

> Multo estas riskata. [A lot is as stake.]

and for *multe*, in this case because it is describing a verb:

> En Okinawa multe pluvas. [It rains a lot in Okinawa.]

You may see both *multe* and *multo* in something like *"multe/multo da arboj"*, but *multe* is far more common. So I suppose use your own judgement, but personally I'll only use *multo* if it's strictly defined as a subject or object.

Comment: What do you actually mean by *makes the most grammatical sense*? And is it wrong to use *multe* as a subject(like I think Jonny M does in "Dankon", singing "[multe okazis, multe sukcesis](http://kantaro.ikso.net/dankon_de_jonny_m)")?

Comment: keep in mind, in those instances multe still describes a verb, so the adverb form is best. Also, Jonny M is great.

Comment: ah, I think you are right about the lyrics. But it doesn't answer the questions in my comment.

Comment: Then, is "Pluvas multo" wrong?

Comment: @svendvn I suppose I was being redundant, sorry for the confusion.
@ AntoniaMontaro You could get away with "pluvas multon", but "pluvas multe" is more frequent.

Comment: @matthewncover Your answer is misleading, as you say that *multe* is an adverb without explicitly clarifying that as an adverb of quantity, it can also be used in a noun-like way (see my answer). Your last comment also has a mistake: *pluvi* can never take an object, so "pluvas multon" is wrong. And as clarified in my answer, the grammatically correct sentence "pluvas multo" would probably not be understood as synonymous with "pluvas multe".

Answer (score 2):

That is simple. You can use *multo* as a description of a big number of something countable. For example *multo da tabloj*. Like you say - ten, hundred, thousand - *multo*. And, sure, *multo* is a noun

*Multe* can be used as a description of something uncountable. *Pluvas multe* - "It rains a lot". *Multe* - adverb

Comment: I don't think it is related to countability. _Multo_ is a noun, while _multe_ is an adverb. Adverbs modify verbs (as in your _pluvas multe_ example) or adjectives (_Li estas multe longa_).

Comment: Agreed. I also ment that "multo" is a noun, that can describe like other counts, like "hundred" or "million". I mentioned countability to explain, that you can't say "pluvas multo". But now I understand, it wasn't a really good explanation. Thank you for correction.

Comment: "Multe" can not only function in an adverbial way (as in "Pluvas multe"), but also in a noun-like way, as in "Mi havas multe por rakonti". See my answer for a clarification.