# Why do they use 'multe' instead of 'multo'?

Tags: adverbs, nouns

I thought 'multe' is an adverb and 'multo' is a corresponding noun.

In this sentence,

> Ili vendas multe da spicoj kaj oleoj

it looks quite weird to me why an adverb multe is used instead of a noun 'multon'.

Answer (score 1):

The basic word is the **adjective *multa*** for which PIV gives three [definitions](https://vortaro.net/#multa_kd) (my translations; all examples from Zamenhof via PIV):

1. big undefinied part of some large set which cannot be expressed with a number: *la tro multa parolado lacigas lin*
2. (in plural) big undefinied set of enumerable things in relation to a small set: *el multaj milonoj fariĝas milionoj*
3. (in plural without a noun) a large group of people: *multaj serĉas favoron de reganto*

From the definition 2 follows that you can say *Ili vendas multajn spicojn kaj oleojn*.

The **adverb *multe*** also has three definitions:

1. denotes a long-lasting or a repeating event: *ne multe dormi*
2. denotes an event which concerns a large group (of something) or is relative intense: *kiu multe profitas, ankaŭ perdon ne evitas*
3. emphasises the comparison: *akiro de saĝeco estas multe pli bona, ol oro*

You connect a quantifying adverb to a noun using the preposition *da*, and thus you can say *Ili vendas multe da spicoj kaj oleo*.

There is also the **noun *multo*** which has only one definition: a large group or quantity: *mi neniam prenas kun mi multon da pakaĵo*.

---

From the definitions follow that the adjective describes the quantify, the adverb the action and the noun stands for the quantity itself.

- *Ili vendas multajn spicojn kaj oleojn.* : They sell many spices and oils.
- *Ili vendas multe da spicoj kaj oleoj.* : They sell lots of spices and oils.
- *Ili vendas multon da spicoj kaj oleoj.* : They sell a lot of spices and oils.

The first one speaks about large selection while the other two of big sales volumes. When it comes to the last two cases, *multe* and *multo* are interchangeable, but for some reason the latter is very rare. I have seen it mostly without a noun (e.g. *Ne restas multo por fari.*).

Note that *multe* and *multo* are not always interchangeable. For this you might want to take a look at [Marcos Cramer's answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/1942/1576) to [*What is difference between "multo" and "multe"?*](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/what-is-difference-between-multo-and-multe)